# WPF Path object StrokeThickness setting has no effect

Tags: wpf, xaml, shapes

I'm drawing a simple `Path` shows a simple triangle pointing down.  This is what it's supposed to draw (shown on top of other stuff)

[image]

It works great except for one thing:  No matter what value I give to the `StrokeThickness`, the triangle what shows up on my screen is the above picture.  It never gets any thicker or thinner.

Here is the XAML.  In this I have set the `StrokeThickness` to the absurd value of "200" just to see if anything would change.  It didn't

```
<Path  Grid.Row="0" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform" 
    StrokeThickness="200"
    Data="{StaticResource ReplicaSurfacePathGeometry}"
    Fill="White" 
    />
```

This is the `Geometry` resource being drawn

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="ReplicaSurfacePathGeometry" FillRule="NonZero">
    <PathGeometry.Figures>
        m 600 1034.3 -501.52 -868.68
        h1003
        z
        
        m 0 -120 397.6 -688.69
        h-795.2
        z
    </PathGeometry.Figures>
</PathGeometry>
```

When I debug and use the live visual tree and look at the actual live properties of the path, it shows the `StrokeThickness` is indeed "200".  But the line stays skinny.

I know this is something dumb on my part.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You forgot to set `Stroke`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white line is the difference of the areas of the two triangle segments in the PathGeometry. It has nothing to do with a potential Stroke of the Path.

In order to make the StrokeThickness effective, set the Stroke property in conjunction with a more simple Geometry:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L2,0 1,1.73 Z"
      Width="30" Height="30" Stretch="Uniform" 
      Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2"/>
```

Comment: Ah!.  I did not realize that Paths worked that way.  I figured that each sequence of Path Markup commands in the Geometry would get the `StrokeThickness` applied to it individually.  I tried changing the `FillRule` but that didn't have any effect either.  Thank you.